# Java Beginner: the mechanism behind "|" operator in Shell s = new Shell(d, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE);

Tags: java, operators, swt

hi I was wondering about the mechanism behind the "`|`" operator in the next code.

```
Display d = new Display( );
Shell s = new Shell(d, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE);
```

p.s: I already checked the source code, but didn't understand

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation - not about java, but it's like essential knowledge for any kind of programming. In a nutshell, SWT.CLOSE and SWT.RESIZE are integers which in binary representation only have 1 bit set (but different bits). When you combine them you get the an integer with both those bits set. And each bit sort of represents one option, that way you can keep many options in one integer value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SWT.CLOSE` and `SWT.RESIZE` are int flags. the `|` means `Binary OR` between them which meant for passing both of them.

For example. if `RESIZE = 1 (00000001 binary)` and `CLOSE = 2 (00000010 binary)`, `SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE = 3 (00000011 binary)` and later on the method called will know to respcet them both.

**Edit - what's next**

If the constructor behaves according to the flags, it might look like this:

```
public Shell(Display d, int flags)
{
      if ((flags & SWT.CLOSE) > 0)//the close flag is on
      { /*do some stuff*/ };
      if ((flags & SWT.RESIZE) > 0)
      { /*do some stuff to enable resize..*/ };
}
```

Now, instead of passing many unnecessary arguments to the constructor, we tell it with one argument (flags) many things to do. The first `if` for example, checks if the CLOSE flag is set in flags: `flags = 3 (00000011 binary)` (as we set it before) `SWT.CLOSE = 2 (00000010 binary)` and `flags & SWT.CLOSE = 3 & 2 = 00000010 binary` which is bigger than zero and is set.

Comment: thanks alot but does this mean, that there is an option== 3, why not use it instead ? doesn't this complicate things more ? I mean what's the benefit of doing this

Comment: There could be a lot of possible combinations (2^32). So it's better and easier to use like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's the bitwise OR operator.

Using correct integers it can be used to define options. If your integers are - but not necesseraly - set unique bits in an integer it can be used on the accepting method to select options.

Example:

- Highlight foreground: `001` => 1 (`HIGHLIGHT_FG`)
- Highlight background: `010` => 2 (`HIGHLIGHT_BG`)
- Bold: `100` => 4 (`BOLD`)

So oring the constants `BOLD | HIGHLIGHT_FG` will be `5`.

But it can be defined also a `HIGHLIGHT_ALL` with `011` => 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's the bitwise or operator. In this case it is used for a bitfield, i.e. `SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE` sets two bits in an integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question, exactly?

The pipe operator is a bit-wise inclusive OR operation.

In general when programming, it lets you OR two values bits together. For example,

0001b | 0010b yields 0011.